# How to say something is on discount

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

"Discount" in the regular meaning: a product now costs less than it used to (usually deliberately by the seller).

I saw [*facio pretium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=pretium) is a phrase meaning "to set a price". So maybe *pretrium minorem facere* will work but I'm unsure. Can we use *deduco pretium* to denote making a discount? (could not find any attestations for this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the title you're asking about "something is on discount", but in the body you seem to be talking about "making a discount", so I'll consider both:

- ***remittere** : (aliquid) [dē summā](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/5/110/1726-1744#110), dē pretiō* = means conceding, forgiving, not demanding as much.
- ***concēdere** : pretium, [pretī partem](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1318/1/184/609-630#184), (aliquid) dē pretiō* = a bit more friendly than the above.
- ***dētrahere** : dē summā, aliquid ex summā* = means actively reducing the price, subtracting some part of it.
- ***imminuere** : summam, [pretium](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/914/1/1485/1541-1558#1485), [aliquid dē](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/37/21/1697-1716#21) pretiō* = "to lessen, diminish".
- ***dēcessiōnem** [(dē summā)](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=decessione%20%5Bcic%5D) **facere, concēdere*** = "to give up, make a concession on the price".
- ***remissiōnem facere*** - not attested, but a perfectly possible combo of the first and the last options.

From the point of view of the borrower, "[discount interest](https://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Discount+Interest)" is **jactūra**, with verbs like *[facere](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/57/288/921-938#288)* or *patī*.

I haven't found any attestations or dictionary suggestions for "an item is being sold at a discount price", but based on the above expressions I would probably phrase it as *merx **pretiō** (valdē etc.) **imminūtō** stat/venit* if for some reason I was unsatisfied simply with ***minōre (pretiō)*** or even just ***vīlī.*** Other than that, the seller could use any of the expressions for "making a discount". That is to say, no specialised and established expression seems to be attested to describe the price of the item.

Comment: Also simply *pretium minuere*, e.g. *pretiumque frumenti minutum usque ad ternos nummos* (Tacitus: [Annales, XV, 31](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/tacitus/tac.ann15.shtml#39))

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I'm not 100% sure but I feel that *minuere* is about reducing the whole, as an intrinsic quality, and *imminuere* about reducing a part, as an extrinsic quality; an addition *minūtus* is an adjective meaning "very small, petty". Thus one can say *pretiō aliquid imminūtō* to mean "at a somewhat reduced price", but *pretiō aliquid minūtō* reads like the adjective to me, while *pretium aliquid minuere* sounds questionable, oxymoronic, like "slash the price somewhat". Likewise **pretiō nihil/paulum minūtō* sounds hardly possible, while *imminūtō* works perfectly.